# Complicated expressions with Hibernate Criteria (like "isnull(retryCount,0)<3" )

Tags: java, hibernate, criteria-api

I have some query like

```
SELECT * FROM JobTable 
WHERE isnull(retryCount,0)<3 
AND updatedOn < dateadd(MI,-5,getdate())
```

How to convert it to Criteria api calls? Point to use Criteria is to allow refactoring if fields names will be changed.

For simple things this is looks like

```
criteria.add(Restrictions.lt(JobTable.RETRYCOUNT_FULL, 3));
```

But what about my case?

```
criteria.add(Restrictions.lt(JobTable.UPDATEON_FULL, <???>);
criteria.add(Restrictions.lt( <someexpression(JobTable.RETRYCOUNT_FULL)> , 3));
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure of the correct name but hibernate has some standard functions which are mapped to the dialects functions. They can be used like this

```
Projections.sqlFunction("dateadd", Projections.property("property"), Hibernate.dateTime);
```

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate Criteria API has `Restrictions.sqlRestriction` functions. In these functions you write your SQL the way you like and Hibernate embeds it in to your SQL.

```
criteria.add(Restrictions.sqlRestriction("isnull({alias}" + JobTable.RETRYCOUNT_FULL + ", 0) < ?", 3, new IntegerType());
```